# Schema hasn't been registered for model "ResourceSchema". - nest js

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, schema, nestjs

Hello everyone i am trying to build api with Nest js and mongodb.

i am trying to make relationship between schema and i get that Error when i am trying to populate resource from role

```
[Nest] 12308   - 2019-08-09 4:22 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] Schema hasn't been registered for model "ResourceSchema".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema) +6998ms
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "ResourceSchema".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
```

my RoleSchema

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import {ResourceModel} from './resourceSchema';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

export const RoleSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, 'Role name is required'],
  },
  resources: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'ResourceModel',
  }],
  permissions: [{type: String}],
});
```

my ResourceSchema

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

export const ResourceSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, 'Role type is required'],
  },
  routingInfo: {type: String},
  iconName: {type: String},
  iconType: {type: String},
  subResources: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, ref: 'ResourceModel'}],
});

export const ResourceModel = mongoose.model('Resource', ResourceSchema);
```

my Role service.ts
populate resources array

```
...

@Injectable()
export class RoleService {
  constructor(@InjectModel('roles') private readonly roleModel: Model<Role>) {
  }

  async findAll(): Promise<Role[]> {
    return await this.roleModel.find().populate({path: 'resources', Model: ResourceModel});
  }

// also tried that
 async findAll(): Promise<Role[]> {
    return await this.roleModel.find().populate({path: 'resources', Model: ResourceSchema});
  }
}
```

my resorce mdule

```
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {ResourcesController} from './resources.controller';
import {ResourcesService} from './resources.service';
import {MongooseModule} from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import {ResourceSchema} from '../schemas/resourceSchema';
import {ConfigService} from '../config/config.service';
import {AuthService} from '../auth/auth.service';
import {UsersService} from '../users/users.service';
import {UserSchema} from '../schemas/userSchema';

@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: 'users', schema: UserSchema}]),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: 'resources', schema: ResourceSchema}])],
  providers: [ResourcesService, UsersService, AuthService, ConfigService],
  controllers: [ResourcesController],
  exports: [ResourcesService],
})
export class ResourcesModule {
}
```

so when i do GET REQUEST on postman i get that error
anyone can tell what i am doing wrong?????

Thanks in andvaced

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ResourceSchema` is schema, not model. You need to register it for the model, for example:

```
export const Resource = mongoose.model('Resource', ResourceSchema);
```

Change the ref:

```
subResources: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, ref: 'Resource'}],
```

Then, import it to your service and call:

```
 return await this.roleModel.find().populate({path: 'resources', Model: Resource });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: and the ref? should still be the Schema?
still gives me the error

Comment: Ah you should change the ref too. I forgot it

Comment: change the ref ro 'Resource'?

Comment: also should change the resources at RoleSchema. work as a magic

Comment: btw this is correct way to do nested Schema inside smae schema?

Comment: I don't have much experience with mongoose but in the docs it says `Note: ObjectId, Number, String, and Buffer are valid for use as refs. However, you should use ObjectId unless you are an advanced user and have a good reason for doing so`.

Comment: In my case it was model not being uppercase in Model.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a supporting schema that was never imported into any module. I resolved it by importing that target schema into a random module like so:

```
imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: LoanOfficer.name, schema: LoanOfficerSchema }])]
```