# How to reference Mongoose model in different NestJS module

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

I'm new to NestJS.  I'm sure this is a simple question, but I just can't find the answer.

In the [nest docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#model-injection) it recommends having one module per model.  This involves creating the model using `MongooseModule.forFeature`:

```js
imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Cat', schema: CatSchema }])]
```

The docs say:

> If you also want to use the models in another module, add MongooseModule to the `exports` section of `CatsModule` and import `CatsModule` in the other module

My question is how to reference the model in the new module.

I can see:

1. [How this would be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819504/inject-nestjs-service-from-another-module) if the model had been created using `mongoose.model('Name', MySchema)`
2. [What exports are needed](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/issues/1)
3. [A question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57431221/schema-hasnt-been-registered-for-model-resourceschema-nest-js) that implies this would be done using `import { Model } from 'mongoose'; @InjectModel('name') myModel: Model<MyInterface>)`, but that feel like it repeats the model creation that is done by `MongooseModule.forFeature`, because it's combining mongoose Model with the schema again

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 16):

So I think that method 3 is the correct one.

According to [this comment](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/421#issuecomment-365618029) by @silvelo you do have to separately provide the collection name and the interface when you inject the schema (but not the schema itself):

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: GAME_COLLECTION_NAME, schema: GameSchema },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [GamesController],
  components: [GamesService],
  exports: [GamesService, MongooseModule],
})
export class GamesModule implements NestModule {}

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: USER_COLLECTION_NAME, schema: UserSchema },
    ]),
    GamesModule,
    LinksModule,
  ],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  components: [UsersService],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule implements NestModule {}

@Component()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(GAME_COLLECTION_NAME) private readonly gameModel: Model<Game>,
    @InjectModel(USER_COLLECTION_NAME) private readonly userModel: Model<User>,
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: @InjectModel(GAME_COLLECTION_NAME) private readonly gameModel: Model<Game>

here what is Model<"this value">  ?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on this, but I believe these are the `Game` and `User` document types, created by e.g. `GameSchema & Document` like the example at https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb

Comment: Yes @DerekHill that's correct