# How can I do a cascade delete with mongoose on NestJs?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm relatively new to using Nest.js and I'm encountering an issue with implementing cascade delete functionality through pre middleware. To give you a clear example, I have two models: one related to enrollments and another related to students.

The scenario I'm dealing with is that when a student is deleted, I'd like to cascade delete all the enrollments associated with that particular student.

Student Schema:

```
export type StudentSchema = HydratedDocument<iStudent>;

@Schema({
   toJSON: {
      virtuals: true,
      transform: function (doc: any, ret: any) {
      delete ret._id;
      delete ret.__v;
      return ret;
    },
   },
 })

export class Student {
@Prop()
firstName: string;

@Prop()
lastName: string;

@Prop()
birthDate: Date;

@Prop()
isCustomer: boolean;

@Prop()
email: string;

@Prop()
phone: string;

@Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Tutor" })
tutor: Tutor;
}

const StudentSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Student);

StudentSchema.pre(["find", "findOne"],  function () {
   this.populate("tutor");
});

StudentSchema.virtual('fullname').get(function() {
   return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
});

export { StudentSchema };
```

In this schema, I have defined a Student class with various properties, and I've set up virtuals and pre middleware for population.

Enrollment Schema

```
export type EnrollmentSchema = HydratedDocument<iEnrollment>;

@Schema({
     toJSON: {
     virtuals: true,
     transform: function (doc: any, ret: any) {
     delete ret._id;
     delete ret.__v;
     return ret;
   },
  },
})

export class Enrollment {
@Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Student" })
student: Student;

@Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Course" })
course: Course;

@Prop()
createdAt: Date;

@Prop()
status: string;
}

const EnrollmentSchema = 
SchemaFactory.createForClass(Enrollment);

EnrollmentSchema.pre(["find", "findOne"],  function () {
  this.populate('student course');
});

export { EnrollmentSchema };
```

In this schema, I have an Enrollment class with properties related to students, courses, and other data. I've also configured virtuals and pre middleware for population.

My goal is to automatically delete all the associated enrollments when a student is deleted. I'd appreciate any guidance on how to implement this cascade delete functionality using Nest.js.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Please post both schemas.

Comment: @jQueeny I just edited, sorry actually it is clearer now

Comment: Are you using Mongoose V7? What Model method will you be using to delete the student? `findByIdAndDelete` and `findOneAndDelete` are synonymous and trigger the same middleware hooks so they would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You can cascade delete all the enrollments associated with that particular student like this example

```
StudentSchema.pre(['find', 'findOne', 'remove'], async function (next) {
    const student = this;
  
    if (this.op === 'remove') {
        // Assuming 'Enrollment' is the name of your Enrollment model
        Enrollment.deleteMany({ studentId: student._id }, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            next(err);
          } else {
            next();
          }
        });
    }
  
    // Logic for pre find or findOne middleware
    // Add your own logic here if needed
    next();
});
```

Comment: When I try to implement this solution it gives me this error


The 'deleteMany' property does not exist for the 'typeofEnrollment' type.


Import { Enrollment } from 'src/app/enrollment/models/enrollment.model';

Comment: deleteMany is the function of Enrollment model, confirm it you have imported the model correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `post` hook which will trigger whenever you use `Student.findByIdAndDelete(id)` and `Student.findOneAndDelete({key:'value'})`

```js
StudentSchema.post('findOneAndDelete', async (document, next)=>{
   try{
      if(document){ //< Only run if a student was found during the delete
         const deleteCascade = await Enrollment.deleteMany({student: document._id});
         console.log('Delete Count:', deleteCascade);
         next();
      }
   }catch(err){
      next(err);
   }
});
```

Comment: When I try to implement this solution it gives me this error


The 'deleteMany' property does not exist for the 'typeofEnrollment' type.


Import { Enrollment } from 'src/app/enrollment/models/enrollment.model';

Comment: Yes your Enrollment model needs to be in scope. You need to import it.

Comment: I have already imported the model, but it gives me this error: "the property 'deleteMany' does not exist for the type 'typeofEnrollment'."

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58634286/21972629) help?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution using Nest's interceptors, there are probably better ways.

```
import { Injectable, CallHandler, ExecutionContext, NestInterceptor } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { Vehicle, VehicleDocument } from 'src/vehicle/schema/vehicle.schema';

@Injectable()
export class CascadeDeleteInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Vehicle.name) private readonly vehicleModel: Model<VehicleDocument>,
  ) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap(async () => {
        const id = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().params.id; 
        await this.vehicleModel.deleteMany({customer: id});
      }),
    );
  }
}
```